# Cakephp: Unchecked checkbox not set in controller

Tags: cakephp, checkbox

I have this checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="data[Customer][pec_email]" data-on-label="SI" data-text-label="PEC" data-off-label="NO" value="1" id="CustomerPecEmail">
```

But, by debugging in the controller, when I submit the input value, the field `pec_email` of `Customer` is 1 if and only if I check the checkbox. If I uncheck, no d`ata[Customer][pec_email]` is present. Why?
I generate the checkbox as:

```
echo $this->Form->input('pec_email',array(
        'label'=>false,
        'hiddenField'=>false,
        'div'           =>false,
        'type'          =>'checkbox',

        "data-on-label"=>"SI",
        "data-text-label" => "PEC",
        "data-off-label"=>"NO"));
```

Comment: I did it, read the edited code. And moreover, it does matter, because I am submitting the input to a Controller. For instance, the Helpers are not mandatory...

Answer (score 1):

### hiddenField false

As mentioned [in the docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options-for-select-checkbox-and-radio-inputs) (emphasis added):

> For certain input types (checkboxes, radios) a hidden input is created **so that the key in $this->request->data will exist even without a value specified**

Checkbox and radio inputs are not included in submitted form data (i.e. by browsers - it's simply how html works) *unless* they are selected. If the option `hiddenField` is set to false, there is no hidden form input, which is what ensures the checkbox data is present when not checked.